MySQL Exclude values
I have two tables:
TESTS:



ID
YEAR
DESCRIPTION




0
2023
some text


..
...
...


N
2024
some text



test_prep_materials:



ID
PATH
TID




0
/home/user/file0.pdf
0


..
...
...


M
/home/user/fileM.pdf
0



So any test have prep materials. And some test's have same material.
I want to delete all material's for 2023 tests and DELETE FILES FROM DISK. But 2024 test's may have same path (SAME FILE ON DISK).
So i need to pick all prep materials for 2023 tests and exclude from them all path's which have dependencies in 2024 tests.
I have tried the following, but there are too many results to know if the command was executed correctly.
SELECT `test_prep_materials`.`PATH`, `tests`.`id`, `tests`.`year`, `tests`.`Name_t` 
    from `test_prep_materials` 
    JOIN `tests` ON `test_prep_materials`.`tId` = `tests`.`id` 
    WHERE `tests`.`year` = 2023 
EXCEPT
SELECT `test_prep_materials`.`PATH`, `tests`.`id`, `tests`.`year`, `tests`.`Name_t` 
    from `test_prep_materials` 
    JOIN `tests` ON `test_prep_materials`.`tId` = `tests`.`id` 
    WHERE `tests`.`year` <> 2023 

Can somebody help me understand if my Query right or i am missing something?

Something is wrong here. You say you want to delete materials that are only relevant for 2023 tests and no other years. I expected to find a material ID in the tests table, but instead there is a test ID in the materials table. So each material entry relates to exactly one test, namely the one stated in tid. There cannot be a material entry that is used in more than one test in your data model. Is there something that I don't see?

Your statement :- "I have tried the following, but there are too many results to know if the command was executed correctly." - > why not use this command to check LIMIT 5; if the results corresponds to what you want.

Your EXCEPT will not exclude any rows at all, since the first SELECT contains year 2023 only, and the second SELECT contains only other years. Skip the year and see what happens. (Or do a NOT EXISTS instead.)

@ThorstenKettner , yes if we are speaking about only table in database - i can delete all rows for 2023 tests. But I SHOULD also delete files on disk. But problem is that same file (path in materials) can belong to both 2023 test and 2024 in a same time

In order to find those paths, you'll just have to limit your query to paths: SELECT m.path from test_prep_materials m JOIN tests t ON t.id = m.tId WHERE t.year = 2023 EXCEPT SELECT m.path from test_prep_materials m JOIN tests t ON t.id = m.tId WHERE t.year <> 2023. Or aggregate: SELECT m.path from test_prep_materials m JOIN tests t ON t.id = m.tId GROUP BY m.path HAVING MIN(t.year) = 2023 AND MAX(t.year) = 2023.

It looks like you need paths to delete from past years tests that are not used in any test of this year. If that is the case that means you need paths used in last year and last year only - use Max(YEAR) = Min(YEAR) per PATH and < Max(YEAR) over all:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tests ( ID, YEAR, DESCRIPTION ) AS 
        ( Select 0, 2023, 'some text 0' Union All
          Select 1, 2024, 'some text 1' Union All
          Select 2, 2023, 'some text 2' Union All
          Select 3, 2024, 'some text 3' Union All
          Select 4, 2024, 'some text 4' 
        ),
    test_prep_materials ( ID, PATH, TID ) AS 
        ( Select 100, '/home/user/file0.pdf', 0 Union All 
          Select 101, '/home/user/file0.pdf', 1 Union All 
          Select 102, '/home/user/file3.pdf', 1 Union All 
          Select 103, '/home/user/file3.pdf', 2 Union All 
          Select 104, '/home/user/file4.pdf', 3 Union All 
          Select 105, '/home/user/file4.pdf', 2 Union All 
          Select 106, '/home/user/file4.pdf', 1 Union All 
          Select 107, '/home/user/file5.pdf', 4 Union All 
          Select 108, '/home/user/file6.pdf', 0 
       )

--    S Q L :
Select     tpm.PATH, Max(t.YEAR) as MAX_YEAR, Min(t.YEAR) as MIN_YEAR
From       tests t 
Left Join  test_prep_materials tpm ON(tpm.TID = t.ID)
Group By   tpm.PATH
HAVING     Max(t.YEAR) < ( Select Max(YEAR) From tests )

/*    R e s u l t : 
PATH                    MAX_YEAR  MIN_YEAR
----------------------  --------  --------
/home/user/file6.pdf        2023      2023    */

OR with all the data from tests table:
--    S Q L :
SELECT  t.*, tpm.PATH
FROM    tests t
INNER JOIN ( Select     tpm.PATH, Max(t.YEAR) as MAX_YEAR, Min(t.YEAR) as MIN_YEAR
             From       tests t 
             Left Join  test_prep_materials tpm ON(tpm.TID = t.ID)
             Group By   tpm.PATH
             HAVING     Max(t.YEAR) < ( Select Max(YEAR) From tests )
          ) tpm ON( t.YEAR Between tpm.MIN_YEAR And tpm.MAX_YEAR )
Where   t.YEAR < ( Select Max(YEAR) From tests )

/*    R e s u l t :
ID  YEAR  DESCRIPTION  PATH
--  ----  -----------  ------------------------
0   2023  some text 0  /home/user/file6.pdf
2   2023  some text 2  /home/user/file6.pd      */

NOTE:
If you want to reffer to any specific year within a range (like 2021 till 2026) change the subquery selecting Max(YEAR) over all with the specific year - lets say 2025 - and the result should be paths used before 2025 and not in  2025. That was not in your sample data, though.
...
HAVING     Max(t.YEAR) <  2025
...

This can be tuned even more with different Where clause conditions.
ONE MORE APPROACH:
If you have the period of years from like 2021 untill 2026 and you want to reffer to 2024 seeking previous paths not present in 2024 then you could do something like below, but with hardcoded refference year (2024):
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tests ( ID, YEAR, DESCRIPTION ) AS 
        ( Select 0, 2023, 'some text 0' Union All
          Select 1, 2024, 'some text 1' Union All
          Select 2, 2023, 'some text 2' Union All
          Select 3, 2024, 'some text 3' Union All
          Select 4, 2024, 'some text 4' Union All
          --    new rows below
          Select 5, 2021, 'some text 5' Union All
          Select 6, 2024, 'some text 6' Union All
          Select 7, 2026, 'some text 7' 
        ),
    test_prep_materials ( ID, PATH, TID ) AS 
        ( Select 100, '/home/user/file0.pdf', 0 Union All 
          Select 101, '/home/user/file0.pdf', 1 Union All 
          Select 102, '/home/user/file3.pdf', 1 Union All 
          Select 103, '/home/user/file3.pdf', 2 Union All 
          Select 104, '/home/user/file4.pdf', 3 Union All 
          Select 105, '/home/user/file4.pdf', 2 Union All 
          Select 106, '/home/user/file4.pdf', 1 Union All 
          Select 107, '/home/user/file5.pdf', 4 Union All 
          Select 108, '/home/user/file6.pdf', 0 Union All
          --  new rows below
          Select 108, '/home/user/file6.pdf', 5 Union All
          Select 108, '/home/user/file5.pdf', 6 Union All
          Select 108, '/home/user/file5.pdf', 7 
       )

--    S Q L : 
Select     tpm.PATH, Max(t.YEAR) as MAX_YEAR, Min(t.YEAR) as MIN_YEAR
From       tests t 
Left Join  test_prep_materials tpm ON(tpm.TID = t.ID)
Group By   tpm.PATH
HAVING     Count((Select 1 From tests Where ID = t.ID And Year = 2024)) = 0 And 
           Max(Case When t.YEAR <= 2024 Then t.YEAR Else 9999 End ) < 2024

/*    R e s u l t : 
PATH                    MAX_YEAR  MIN_YEAR
----------------------  --------  --------
/home/user/file6.pdf        2023      2021    */


can u please help me understand your first SQL script? how to redact it in such case, what i can pick from which year exactly i remove materials? for example at some point i can have 2023 - 2026 year. So if i correctly understand Query it will return all materials from 2023 only, 2024 only, 2025 only. And i for example want to delete only for 2025

@ASDORDSAUSER Just updated the answer with ---> HAVING     Max(t.YEAR) < ( Select Max(YEAR) From tests )

I think something wrong with second query.
Test data:
1 - Test1 - 2023
2 - Test2 - 2024
3 - Test3 - 2023
4 - Test4 - 2024

1 - /a/b - 1
2 - /a/b - 2
3 - /c/d - 3
4 - /e/f  - 4
So i expect to see only Test3 - 2023 - /c/d
Got:
Test1 - 2023 - /c/d
Test3 - 2023 - /c/d

@ASDORDSAUSER Fixed that too. Changed ON clause and added WHERE clause. It is needed for multiple past years.

@ASDORDSAUSER See the fiddle with multiple past years -->  https://dbfiddle.uk/4iMQrFg1

idk second Query seems not working properly, still returns 2 values. https://dbfiddle.uk/Yj569teC

@ASDORDSAUSER As it is supposed to and as stated in the answer "OR with all the data from tests table:"  - it shows the rows from tests table assosiated with the PATH(s) in question "/home/user/file6.pdf"...

aaah! Gotcha. That you very much for your help! You saved me!

@ASDORDSAUSER Added one more approach for the case that you have data from past and future years ...

You may use following query, it'll eliminate the common path across both the years & gives you the path that you can delete.
select *from test_prep_materials tpm inner join tests t
on t.id = tpm.tid
where t.year = '2023'
and exists (select path from test_prep_materials tpm2 inner join tests t
                on t.id=tpm.id and t.year = 2024  -- t.year != 2023
                where tpm2.path =tpm.path
           )

